# why cant i read a String in this program after reading String ,Integer and double variables?

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I cannot enter a string in run time `filmType`. Once it reaches the line that asks for a `filmType` the program ends.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner In = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter film name");

    String s = In.nextLine();
    System.out.println("enter Budget");
    int Budget=In.nextInt();

    System.out.println("enter running time");
    double running = In.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("enter film Type");
    String filmType = In.nextLine();    
 }
}
```

Comment: Hello Chalasani Harika, please read the tutorial how to post a question. You will be more likely to receive help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is the use of `nextInt` and `nextDouble`.
These methods do not take into account the newline `\n` (enter) you put in the line you entered at the specific question. This newline will that go to the next time you call a `nextLine` and will immediate assign an empty line to that variable.

You can for instance change your code to:

```
Scanner In = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("enter film name");
String s = In.nextLine();

System.out.println("enter Budget");
String BudgetString = In.nextLine();

int budget = Integer.parseInteger(BudgetString); // with proper numberFormatException handling

System.out.println("enter running time");
String runningString = In.nextLine();

double running = Double.parseDouble(runningString); // with proper numberFormatException handling

System.out.println("enter film Type");
String filmType = In.nextLine();
```